# SDWebImage does not load remote images until scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lazy-loading, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebImage library to load remote images into a table view which uses a custom cell class i have created. I simply use

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.jpg"]];
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
Now the problem is it loads images in the visible cells only and not for cells that are offscreen for which i have to scroll up and down to make them load. Is there any way i can load all images without having to scroll the table view.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure those cells are creating which are offscreen? Do you know about the behavior of UITableView?

Comment: The cells are being reused

Comment: Yes, then which cells are offscreen then the instance method will be called for those cells? It is not the problem of SDWebImage.

Comment: So is this a normal behaviour that images load for only those cells that are visible/onscreen?

Comment: Yes, it is. iOS is designed in this manner to reduce use of memory.

Comment: This concept of loading images for visible cells only, and loading offscreen images as you scroll is called "lazy loading", and is the entire purpose of the class (as well as to do it asynchronously). Do I gather that you want to marry this asynchronous operation with some more "eager loading", i.e. to start to prefetch some of the other images?

Comment: yes..actually i want to prefetch images for offscreen cells so it doesn't look like that image loading is taking time

Comment: @user2082760 The `SDWebImage` classes have all of the interfaces to interact directly with `SDWebImageManager` directly. You can implement your own prefetching routine, though be careful to handle `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. You might want to manage your cache closely, too, perhaps only prefetching some limited number of forthcoming cells. Not many of these classes have built-in prefetch routines, as that's the opposite of what most people are trying to do. But some smart pre-fetch is a good idea. Not too hard, but also not trivial. Do you have a nice model backing your tableview?

Comment: i even tried SDWebImageProgressiveDownload option but the app crashes as i scroll the table and without any crash log..i think it is also low memory issue

Comment: No that's solving another problem, methinks. I'm going onto a call, but if someone hasn't provided you a nice prefetch routine by the time I get back in a few hours, I'll help you out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to prefetch rows, you can respond to `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to determine when the table scrolling is done, triggering a prefetch of the rows. You can perform the prefetch using `SDWebImagePrefetcher` (in my original answer I was a little dismissive of this useful class, but it seems to work relatively well now):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // the details don't really matter here, but the idea is to fetch data, 
    // call `reloadData`, and then prefetch the other images

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kUrlWithJSONData];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (connectionError) {
            NSLog(@"sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", connectionError);
            return;
        }

        self.objects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

        [self prefetchImagesForTableView:self.tableView];
    }];
}

// some of the basic `UITableViewDataDelegate` methods have been omitted because they're not really relevant
```

Here is the simple `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (not entirely relevant, but just showing that if you use `SDWebImagePrefetcher`, you don't have to mess around with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]], @"cell should be CustomCell");

    [cell.customImageView setImageWithURL:[self urlForIndexPath:indexPath] placeholderImage:nil];
    [cell.customLabel setText:[self textForIndexPath:indexPath]];

    return cell;
}
```

These `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods prefetch more rows when scrolling finishes

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    // if `decelerate` was true for `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`
    // this will be called when the deceleration is done

    [self prefetchImagesForTableView:self.tableView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    // if `decelerate` is true, then we shouldn't start prefetching yet, because
    // `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be hard at work returning cells for the currently visible
    // cells.

    if (!decelerate)
        [self prefetchImagesForTableView:self.tableView];
}
```

You obviously need to implement a prefetch routine. This gets the `NSIndexPath` values for the cells on each side of the visible cells, gets their image URLs, and then prefetches that data.

```
/** Prefetch a certain number of images for rows prior to and subsequent to the currently visible cells
 *
 * @param  tableView   The tableview for which we're going to prefetch images.
 */

- (void)prefetchImagesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    if ([indexPaths count] == 0) return;

    NSIndexPath *minimumIndexPath = indexPaths[0];
    NSIndexPath *maximumIndexPath = [indexPaths lastObject];

    // they should be sorted already, but if not, update min and max accordingly

    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths)
    {
        if (indexPath.section < minimumIndexPath.section || (indexPath.section == minimumIndexPath.section && indexPath.row < minimumIndexPath.row)) minimumIndexPath = indexPath;
        if (indexPath.section > maximumIndexPath.section || (indexPath.section == maximumIndexPath.section && indexPath.row > maximumIndexPath.row)) maximumIndexPath = indexPath;
    }

    // build array of imageURLs for cells to prefetch

    NSMutableArray *imageURLs = [NSMutableArray array];
    indexPaths = [self tableView:tableView priorIndexPathCount:kPrefetchRowCount fromIndexPath:minimumIndexPath];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths)
        [imageURLs addObject:[self urlForIndexPath:indexPath]];
    indexPaths = [self tableView:tableView nextIndexPathCount:kPrefetchRowCount fromIndexPath:maximumIndexPath];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths)
        [imageURLs addObject:[self urlForIndexPath:indexPath]];

    // now prefetch

    if ([imageURLs count] > 0)
    {
        [[SDWebImagePrefetcher sharedImagePrefetcher] prefetchURLs:imageURLs];
    }
}
```

These are the utility methods for getting the `NSIndexPath` for the rows immediately preceding the visible cells as well as those immediately following the visible cells:

```
/** Retrieve NSIndexPath for a certain number of rows preceding particular NSIndexPath in the table view.
 *
 * @param  tableView  The tableview for which we're going to retrieve indexPaths.
 * @param  count      The number of rows to retrieve
 * @param  indexPath  The indexPath where we're going to start (presumably the first visible indexPath)
 *
 * @return            An array of indexPaths.
 */

- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView priorIndexPathCount:(NSInteger)count fromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (row == 0) {
            if (section == 0) {
                return indexPaths;
            } else {
                section--;
                row = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] - 1;
            }
        } else {
            row--;
        }
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
    }

    return indexPaths;
}

/** Retrieve NSIndexPath for a certain number of following particular NSIndexPath in the table view.
 *
 * @param  tableView  The tableview for which we're going to retrieve indexPaths.
 * @param  count      The number of rows to retrieve
 * @param  indexPath  The indexPath where we're going to start (presumably the last visible indexPath)
 *
 * @return            An array of indexPaths.
 */

- (NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView nextIndexPathCount:(NSInteger)count fromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger rowCountForSection = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        row++;
        if (row == rowCountForSection) {
            row = 0;
            section++;
            if (section == [tableView numberOfSections]) {
                return indexPaths;
            }
            rowCountForSection = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
        }
        [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
    }

    return indexPaths;
}
```

There's a lot there, but in reality, `SDWebImage` and its `SDWebImagePrefetcher` is doing the heavy lifting.

I include my original answer below for the sake of completeness.

---

Original answer:

If you want to do some prefetching with `SDWebImage`, you could do something like the following:

1. Add a completion block to your `setImageWithURL` call:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

       static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

       TableModelRow *rowData = self.objects[indexPath.row];

       cell.textLabel.text = rowData.title;
       [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:rowData.url
                      placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                 [self prefetchImagesForTableView:tableView];
                             }];

       return cell;
   }
   ```

   I must confess I don't really like calling my `prefetcher` routine here (I wish iOS had some nice `didFinishTableRefresh` delegate method), but it works, even if it's calling the routine more times than I'd really want. I just make sure below that the routine below makes sure that it won't make redundant requests.
2. Anyway, I write a prefetch routine that looks for, say, the next ten images:

   ```
   const NSInteger kPrefetchRowCount = 10;

   - (void)prefetchImagesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
       // determine the minimum and maximum visible rows

       NSArray *indexPathsForVisibleRows = [tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
       NSInteger minimumVisibleRow = [indexPathsForVisibleRows[0] row];
       NSInteger maximumVisibleRow = [indexPathsForVisibleRows[0] row];

       for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPathsForVisibleRows)
       {
           if (indexPath.row < minimumVisibleRow) minimumVisibleRow = indexPath.row;
           if (indexPath.row > maximumVisibleRow) maximumVisibleRow = indexPath.row;
       }

       // now iterate through our model;
       // `self.objects` is an array of `TableModelRow` objects, one object
       // for every row of the table.

       [self.objects enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(TableModelRow *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
           NSAssert([obj isKindOfClass:[TableModelRow class]], @"Expected TableModelRow object");

           // if the index is within `kPrefetchRowCount` rows of our visible rows, let's
           // fetch the image, if it hasn't already done so.

           if ((idx < minimumVisibleRow && idx >= (minimumVisibleRow - kPrefetchRowCount)) ||
               (idx > maximumVisibleRow && idx <= (maximumVisibleRow + kPrefetchRowCount)))
           {
               // my model object has method for initiating a download if needed

               [obj downloadImageIfNeeded];
           }
       }];
   }
   ```
3. In the downloading routine, you can check to see if the image download has started and, if not, then start it. To do this with `SDWebImage`, I keep a `weak` pointer to the web image operation in my `TableModelRow` class (the model class that backs the individual rows of my table):

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, weak) id<SDWebImageOperation> webImageOperation;
   ```

   I then have the `downloadImageIfNeeded` routine start a download if it hasn't already (you can see why making that `weak` was so important ... I'm checking to see if this row already has an operation pending before starting another). I'm not doing anything with the downloaded image (short of, for debugging purposes, logging the fact that a download was done), but rather just downloading and letting `SDImageWeb` keep track of the cached image for me, so when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` later requests the image as the user scrolls down, it's there, ready and waiting.

   ```
   - (void)downloadImageIfNeeded
   {
       if (self.webImageOperation)
           return;

       SDWebImageManager *imageManager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];

       self.webImageOperation = [imageManager downloadWithURL:self.url
                                                      options:0
                                                     progress:nil
                                                    completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%s: downloaded %@", __FUNCTION__, self.title);
                                                        // I'm not going to do anything with the image, but `SDWebImage` has now cached it for me
                                                    }];
   }
   ```

   Part of me thinks it might be more robust to call `imageManager.imageCache` instance method `queryDiskCacheForKey` first, but after doing some testing, it doesn't look like that's needed (and the `downloadWithURL` does that for us, anyway).

I should point out that the `SDImageWeb` library does have a `SDWebImagePrefetcher` class (see [the documentation](http://hackemist.com/SDWebImage/doc/Classes/SDWebImagePrefetcher.html)). The name of the class is incredibly promising, but looking at the code, with all deference to an otherwise excellent library, this doesn't feel very robust to me (e.g. it is a simple list of URLs to fetch and if you do it again, it cancels the prior list with no notion of "adding to the queue" or anything like that). It's a promising notion, but a little weak in execution. And when I tried it, my UX suffered noticeably.

So, I'm inclined to not use `SDWebImagePrefetcher` (until it's improved, at least), and stick to my rudimentary  prefetching technique. It's not terribly sophisticated, but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I suggest a slight improvement to this answer like how apple does lazy loading in their example. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). Why not use '- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate' and '- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
'

Comment: @AnilPuttabuddhi Agreed, you can trigger this with those `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods. I've updated my answer with a rendition that not only does this, but employs `SDWebImagePrefetcher`, too. I believe this rendition also better handles multiple sections, as well.

Comment: Great example, thank you, I adopted some portions of this code, however I am missing one piece. Lets say a user clicked on a pic and transitioned into a different view (I stopped preloading obviously), then eventually user went back into collection view, I want to trigger preloading again around my current location, however visible array is empty. Not sure how to trigger initial preloading either when view is first displayed and hasn't been dragged yet. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just had to solve this exact problem and didn't want the overhead of the prefetcher. There must be some extra under-the-hood stuff happening with the built-in imageView property that prevents the loading, because a new UIImageView works just fine.

My solution is pretty clean if you don't mind (or are already) using a subclass of UITableViewCell:

1. Subclass UITableViewCell.
2. In your subclass, hide self.imageView.
3. Create your own UIImageView subview and set *this* view's image.

Here's a modified version of my own code (undocumented here is setting the frame to match the size & position of the iOS Photo app's album covers):

**YourTableCell.h**

```
@interface YourTableCell : UITableViewCell
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *coverPhoto;
@end
```

**YourTableCell.m**

```
@implementation YourTableCell

@synthesize coverPhoto;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.imageView.image = nil;
        self.coverPhoto = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        // Any customization, such as initial image, frame bounds, etc. goes here.        

        [self.contentView addSubview:self.coverPhoto];
    }
    return self;
}
//...
@end
```

**YourTableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    YourTableCell *cell = (YourTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //...
    [cell.coverPhoto setImageWithURL:coverUrl placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example and you need to implement this for your purpose.

**your UITableView delegate:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourCustomTableViewCellReuseIdentifier"];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[YourCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];        
    }

    NSString *imageURL = // ... get image url, typically from array
    [cell loadImageWithURLString:imageURL forIndexPath:indexPath]; 

    return cell;
}
```

**your custom UITableViewCell .h file**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"

@interface YourCustomTableViewCell
{
    NSIndexPath *currentLoadingIndexPath;
}

- (void)loadImageWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

@end
```

**your custom UITableViewCell .m file**:

```
// ... some other methods

- (void)loadImageWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    currentLoadingIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.imageView cancelCurrentImageLoad];
    [self.imageView setImage:nil];

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:imageURL
                   placeholderImage:nil
                            options:SDWebImageRetryFailed
                          completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
    {
        if (currentLoadingIndexPath != indexPath)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (error)
        {
            ... // handle error
        }
        else
        {
            [imageView setImage:image];
        }
    }];
}

// ... some other methods
```

`currentLoadingIndexPath` needed to detect if we reuse this cell for another image instead of image which was downloaded while user scrolls the table view.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem，I found UIImageView+WebCache cancel last download when  a new download come.

I not sure whether this is the intention of the author. So I write a new `category` of UIImageView base on SDWebImage.

Easy to use:

```
[cell.imageView mq_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                   groupIdentifier:@"customGroupID"
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                         }];
```

To view more: [ImageDownloadGroup](https://github.com/maquannene/MQImageDownloadGroup)

Advanced usage:

```
//  create customGroup
MQImageDownloadGroup *customGroup = [[MQImageDownloadGroup alloc] initWithGroupIdentifier:@"tableViewCellGroup"];
customGroup.maxConcurrentDownloads = 99;

//  add to MQImageDownloadGroupManage
[[MQImageDownloadGroupManage shareInstance] addGroup:customGroup];

//  use download group
[cell.imageView mq_setImageWithURL:@"https://xxx"
                   groupIdentifier:@"tableViewCellGroup"
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                         }];
```