# AFNetworking prefetch other images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, afnetworking

I am using the `UIImageView + AFNetworking` category to download and display images from an array of URLs and populate a table view.

Now I find that the other images are delayed because only the current cell's image will be loaded. I need to keep busy by fetching other images as well.

My idea would be to write a for loop and start downloading and caching with AFNetworking, say,  10 other requests `starting from current indexPath`.

Or should I just do the usual `dispatch_async` in the completion block and start fetching the mentioned 20 other images?

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, pre-fetching won't be nearly as beneficial as you might expect. On a mobile device, power and bandwidth are limited resources, which calls into question the value of loading things that a user may not actually ever see. You're most likely doing a disservice by trying to be clever about this.

Comment: Now, I believe that **questioning the value of loading things that a user may not actually ever see** is subject to interpretation and user experience. If I am scrolling through images, won't it be good if some of those images preloaded? The comments I receive from some users are like, what happened to the other images, and why aren't they loading? Of course now we can talk about mobile device limitations. But I would like to try (maybe fail). I tried, but it kinda sucks :P I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Oh and by the way, you can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701556/sdwebimage-does-not-load-remote-images-until-scroll) link.

Comment: @BlackFlam3 There are a thousand other things you can do to improve user experience in a more significant way. You're probably much better off spending your development time on something else.